# Copy a sheet from one wb to another wb, but copy values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code adding sheets from one workbook to another. However, I only want to add the values and not the formulae. How do I achieve this?

```
Sub publish()
    Dim new_wb As Workbook
    Dim old_wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim new_file_path As String

    Call refresh_output_sheets

    new_file_path = Range("output_path").Value
    Set old_wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set new_wb = Workbooks.Add

    For Each sh In old_wb.Sheets
        If InStr(LCase(sh.CodeName), "output") <> 0 Then
            sh.Copy After:=new_wb.Sheets(new_wb.Sheets.Count)
        End If
    Next sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Not thoroughly tested but hopefully this will get you close.  Replace your copy loop with something like this:

```
    For Each sh In old_wb.Sheets
        If InStr(LCase(sh.CodeName), "output") <> 0 Then
            sh.Copy
            new_wb.Sheets(new_wb.Sheets.Count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next sh
```

If it's giving you fits, let me know and I'll do some more testing.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have copied a worksheet to the new workbook, activate it and run this:

```
Sub ClearFormulas()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents
End Sub
```

So basically, remove the formulas **after** the copy has been made.

Comment: @LS_Dev: On my computer, only cells containing formulas are cleared.....cells containing data are not cleared....can you confirm this??

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    ...
    sh.Copy After:=new_wb.Sheets(new_wb.Sheets.Count)
    new_wb.Sheets(new_wb.Sheets.Count).Cells.Values=sh.Cells.Values
End If
...
```

As you know, first statement will copy all data.

Then, new worksheet values are assigned from source, removing all formulas.

I find useful make `.Copy` before using `.Value` to copy formats, column widths, ...